# Are there different definitions of a continuous time Markov chain, condition on a finite or infinite number of earlier values?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

My book defines a continuous time Markov chain like this.

Let $\{X_t\}, t \in T$ be a stochastic process on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, with a countable state space $S$. The process is a Markov chain, if for all

$n>0, t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n <t_{n+1} \in T$ and   $i_1,i_2,\ldots i_{n+1} \in S$

With

$P[X_{t_1} =i_1 \ldots X_{t_n} =i_1]>0$, the following statement holds:

$P[X_{t_{n+1}}=i_{n+1}| X_{t_k}=i_k \forall k \le n]=P[X_{t_{n+1}}=i_{n+1}|X_{t_n}=i_n]$

The problem here is that he only has the definition for a finite number of previous values. But in a proof he seems to use that it holds for a set that may contain countable infinite values. What is the usual definition given, is it conditioned on a finite number, countably infinite or may uncountable infinite like an interval?

If we only have this definition for n, arbitrary but finite. And we condition on a countable number of previous events, is it then true that we might just have conditioned on the last one, like is usual for Markov chains, or does the fact that we have conditioned on an infinite number of previous values, may give us more information?

Comment: The only issue is that there should be a maximum element of the set of times when you are conditioning. This is of course always true in the finite case but is not always true in the infinite case. But in that case, if you condition at times given by members of a countable set with a maximum, it's the same as conditioning at just the maximum time.

Comment: I should say: the maximum should also be an isolated point. Otherwise you may be conditioning on something of probability zero and create problems that way.

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much, could you please give some hint on how to prove this?